# Imagemosaic no-data pixels problem transparency

Tags: geoserver, sld, overlay, transparency-opacity, image-mosaic

I'm trying to display imagemosaic where image are irregular and near each other.
Imagemosaic are displayed with a SLD
Images overlap and no transparency is applied

When publish imagemosaic, I set BackgroundValues as -999
If try to set InputTransparentColor or OutputTransparentColor, but I have exception on GeoServer.

I use:
GeoServer 2.8.0
apache-tomcat-7.0.57 with java 1.8.0_101 64bit
windows7

My SLD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld      http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>gtopo</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>ndvi</Name>
      <Title>NDVI style</Title>
      <Abstract>NDVI color progression</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>500000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1</Opacity>
            <ColorMap>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00FF00" quantity="-999" label="values" opacity="0.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF0000" quantity="0" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF4800" quantity="0.125" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FF9500" quantity="0.250" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFE100" quantity="0.375" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#D0FF00" quantity="0.50" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#84FF00" quantity="0.625" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#37FF00" quantity="0.75" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00FF16" quantity="0.875" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#00FF00" quantity="1" label="values" opacity="1.0"/>
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

gdal info image (no data value is -999)

```
E:\DevApps\testCaseImageMosaic>gdalinfo 180690_92_S2A_MSIL2A_20180106T100401_N0206_R122_T32TQQ_20180106T120734.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 180690_92_S2A_MSIL2A_20180106T100401_N0206_R122_T32TQQ_20180106T120734.tif
Size is 943, 606
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (12.281968477673896,45.019667104849084)
Pixel Size = (0.000015804510078,-0.000015804510078)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  12.2819685,  45.0196671) ( 12d16'55.09"E, 45d 1'10.80"N)
Lower Left  (  12.2819685,  45.0100896) ( 12d16'55.09"E, 45d 0'36.32"N)
Upper Right (  12.2968721,  45.0196671) ( 12d17'48.74"E, 45d 1'10.80"N)
Lower Right (  12.2968721,  45.0100896) ( 12d17'48.74"E, 45d 0'36.32"N)
Center      (  12.2894203,  45.0148783) ( 12d17'21.91"E, 45d 0'53.56"N)
Band 1 Block=943x2 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-999
```

I tried to use other geoserver, but I have exception whene publish imagemosaic:

GeoServer 2.12.1: imagemosaic doesn't work

GeoServer 2.11.4: imagemosaic doesn't work

```
10 gen 15:55:13 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file://E:\DevApps\testCaseImageMosaic
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file://E:\DevApps\testCaseImageMosaic and hints null
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:158)
```

GeoServer 2.10.5: imagemosaic doesn't work

```
10 gen 16:18:00 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Unable to convert coverage URL to a URI, attempting to use it as a path
10 gen 16:18:00 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file://E:\DevApps\testCaseImageMosaic
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file://E:\DevApps\testCaseImageMosaic and hints null
```

imagemosaic overlap

[image: imagemosaic overlap]

original images on ArcGIS

[image]

Someone can help us to solve this problem?